# Set up Google Play services in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I want to modify the MainActivity.java file, for a custom android implementation. To do that, i need to include google libraries, like LocationServices.

Eg, to use ..

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

I looked at the official google documentation
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

And I can see this line, which must be added in build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
}
```

I try to add this line in my "build.gradle" file, but maybe it's wrong

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    }
}
```

When I run "gradlew build", I get this error:

Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

This is the default "build.gradle" file for flutter.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What's the correct way to import those google libs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the dependency to the wrong file.
In the photo, you can see the location of the correct build.gradle file and the line where you will add the dependency.

I took a screenshot for you;

[image]

Comment: That was the problem. Now it works. Thanks